# How to write on an NFC tag? (Ionic)

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, nfc

I have a button that calls the test2 function

This is my code:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NFC, Ndef } from '@ionic-native/nfc/ngx';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-tab3',
  templateUrl: 'tab3.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['tab3.page.scss']
})
export class Tab3Page {

  constructor( private nfc: NFC, private ndef: Ndef,) {
  }

  test2(){
    this.nfc.addNdefListener(() => {
      console.log('successfully attached ndef listener');
    }, (err) => {
      console.log('error attaching ndef listener', err);
    }).subscribe(() => {      
      console.log("works");
      let message = [this.ndef.textRecord("hello, world")];
      this.nfc.share(message);
    }, err => console.log(err));
    
  }   
 
  }
```

However the subscribe does not trigger as soon as I pass my NFC tag to it. The addNdefListener is triggered correctly, what is wrong?

I am using IONIC 5.6 with capacitor, I also use the native NFC plugin.

Can you help me? please

Comment: I'm guessing this is on Android? The question is what Android Version?

Comment: Yeap, Android 9.0

Answer (score 0):

`nfc.share` is for Peer to Peer between two devices and this has been dropped in Android 10 BUT your Question Title say "write on an NFC Tag" for which you need to use `nfc.write`

As Device to Device NFC protocol is totally different to Device to Tag Protocol.

Answer (score 0):

I changed it as you said, but it didn't work, however, I went back to read all the documentation and I didn't see any error with what I was writing, so I decided to create a new project and redo my code, and it worked, it is likely that the files were corrupted, but I fixed it, thanks for your support.